# Bootstrap Modal Issue with Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 buttons and modals. If I am using bootstrap.js then the modal is disappearing. I wrote jquery modal function but it is not working properly could any one help me. [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ku1gdLoq/2/) Link

Button Code

```
<button id="modal1" class="">ModalA</button>
<button id="modal2" class="">ModalB</button>
```

Modal Code

```
<div class="modal modal-sm fade in" id="modal1" >
  <div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <h5 class='modal-title'>Modal title</h5>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>
          <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-body'>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='modal-footer'>");
      <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="modal modal-sm fade in" id="modal2" >
  <div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <h5 class='modal-title'>Modal title</h5>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>
          <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-body'>
        <h1>I am modal B</h1>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='modal-footer'>");
      <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$("button").click(function() {
  var idValue = $(this).attr("id");
  //alert(idValue);
  $('#' + idValue).modal('show');
  $('#'+idValue).modal({backdrop: false});
  $('#'+idValue).modal({keyboard: true});
});
```

Comment: I think you misspelled "true" as "ture" in the second-to-last line.

Comment: I am getting same problem after changing 'ture' to 'true'. After clicking the button is also disappearing. Updated link http://jsfiddle.net/ku1gdLoq/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the same `id's` in two places. Look at `button#modal1` and `.modal#modal1`.
The `id's` from buttons are not necessary, you can remove them and also your `jquery modal` function.

And for **bootstrap modal** add to both buttons `data-toggle="modal"` `data-target="the modal container id"`

**Please check it out:**
https://jsfiddle.net/coheafof/

Comment: data-target and data-toggle are not working in my program. If I use data-target and data-toggle attributes modal is disappearing immediately  that is why i am writing jquery function.

Comment: you can use data attributes ? Using the same id in two places is not possible

Comment: Yes, I changed id values. please check out in this updated link http://jsfiddle.net/ku1gdLoq/6/

Comment: you also use the same id's in two places

Comment: Thank you, jsfiddle.net/ku1gdLoq/7 is worked for my problem